# calling an external method to change a storage variable, when will that change be reflected?

Tags: solidity

In a method doStuff on contract LOC I have a call to an external contract EXT to change a storage variable A on that contract from 0 to 1. Later in the same doStuff method I set LOC storage variable B equal to A.
If A is initially 0 and then I call doStuff on LOC, will B end up as 0 or 1?

Answer (score 0):

The change will be reflected, as you call it. Line by line. Right away. See below:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract EXT {
    uint256 public A = 0;

    function setA(uint256 _a) public {
        A = _a;
    }
}

contract LOC {
    uint256 public B;
    EXT externalContract;

    function setAddress(address _address) public {
        externalContract = EXT(_address);
    }

    function doStuff() public {
        externalContract.setA(1);
        B = externalContract.A();
    }
}
```

If that is what you mean, after calling **doStuff()**, **B** will equal **1**.

PS. You could try that in [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/)